# Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 8.0.5 but source was compiled with: 8.1.0

Tags: tensorflow

I get this error when I run the model.fit_generator code to train images using the CNN model. I don't understand the error, and what should I do? Can anyone help me?
this is the full error description

```
Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 8.0.5, but the source was compiled with: 8.1.0.  
CuDNN library needs to have a matching major version and equal or higher minor version. If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library.
If building from sources, ensure the library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version specified during compile configuration.
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error  "tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:362] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 8.0.5 but source was compiled with: 8.1.0."
I solved it by downgrading the TensorFlow version, here it says that you use a new version of TensorFlow that is not compatible with the google colab CuDNN version. I used TensorFlow 2.4.0 plus all the dependence required on version 2.4.0.
Here it says which version of TensorFlow to use for cudnn compatibility, https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source

Comment: Thanks, your solution works in my case as my `CUDA Version: 11.7` is not compatible with `tensorflow>=tensorflow-2.11.0`

Answer (score 1):

You should always have version of libraries installed that is matching the version dependency you want to use is compiled with.

You can download the version you need from [nvidia website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) or use conda for package management. It will handle all dependencies for you.

You can [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) and type `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu` to get it sorted for you. If you need a specific version of python, you can create environment with it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

After confirming that my cuda and cudnn versions are compatible with tensorflow, I first thought that the system did not synchronize after the installation was completed. After several restarts, it was found that it was not and could not be the problem, so I started to check all the cuda in the system. For the software that depends on cudnn, matlab was uninstalled during the period but it was useless. Later, I thought that pytorch is also related to cuda and cudnn. I checked the version of pytorch and found that I was using torch 1.8, and the cuda it was adapted to was 11.1 , The corresponding cudnn is 8.0.5, now the case is solved. Finally upgraded pytorch and solved it.

Comment: Would you elaborate on this please? How did you upgrade pytorch? Thanks

Comment: go to the official page of pytorch and install the corresponding pytorch, torchvision and torchtext verison

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. It seems like if TensorFlow versions requires specific cuDNN version.
Check the link for required versions.
[https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#:%7E:text=GPU-,Version,CUDA,-tensorflow%2D2.8.0)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for This answer.

> My solution:
> After confirming that my cuda and cudnn versions are compatible with
> tensorflow, I first thought that the system ...

It helps me a lot,but I use different way to solve this problem.
I found that pytorch 1.8 is compatible with cudnn 8.1.0. So, instead of upgrade pytorch version, I overwrite the cudnn 8.0.5 dll library with cudnn 8.1.0 in directory D:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib. You can find this location with Everything, which is always helpful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade or downgrade, according to this information:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source?hl=es-419#gpu